# Optimization issue with python pulp

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, google-colaboratory, pulp

I tried to create a small optimization problem with python using pulp.
The goal is to optimize energy consumption and storage decisions over a 24-hour time horizon, taking into account renewable energy supply, grid energy costs, and a battery with specific parameters.

```
import pulp

# Define the optimization problem
prob = pulp.LpProblem("Energy_Cost_Minimization", pulp.LpMinimize)

# Time horizon
T = 24

# Battery parameters
B_max = 10     # Maximum battery capacity
B_init = 0     # Initial battery level

# Grid energy cost per unit for each hour
grid_cost = [
    0.15, 0.15, 0.14, 0.13, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.14, 0.16,
    0.18, 0.20, 0.20, 0.20, 0.18, 0.16, 0.14, 0.18, 0.20, 0.20,
    0.20, 0.18, 0.16, 0.15
]

# Renewable energy supply for each hour
S = [
    1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1
]

# Predicted energy demand for each hour
D = [
    0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3, 3, 2.5, 2.5,
    2.5, 3, 3.5, 3.5, 3, 2, 1.5, 1
]

# Create decision variables
G = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("Grid Energy", range(T), lowBound=0)
B = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("Battery Level", range(T), lowBound=0, upBound=B_max)

# Objective function
prob += pulp.lpSum(grid_cost[t] * G[t] for t in range(T))

# Constraints
for t in range(T):
    # Renewable surplus calculation
    Surplus = max(0, S[t] - D[t])
    
    # Battery charging constraints
    if t == 0:
        prob += B[t] == B_init
        prob += G[t] + S[t] == D[t]
    else:
        prob += B[t] == B[t-1] + Surplus
        prob += G[t] + S[t] + B[t] == D[t]
    
    # Battery level should not exceed its maximum capacity
    prob += B[t] <= B_max

# Solve optimization
prob.solve()

# Print results
for t in range(T):
    print(f"Hour {t}: Grid Energy = {G[t].varValue} kWh, Battery Level = {B[t].varValue} kWh, Power Consumption = {D[t]} kWh, Renewable Energy Supply = {S[t]} kWh")
```

Grid energy should be used when battery and renewable energy aren't enough but it is 0 at all hours and battery also should charge only when is a surplus of energy but doesn't work.

> Hour 0: Grid Energy = 0.0 kWh, Battery Level = 0.0 kWh, Power Consumption = 0.5 kWh, Renewable Energy Supply = 1 kWh

> Hour 1: Grid Energy = 0.0 kWh, Battery Level = 0.0 kWh, Power Consumption = 0.5 kWh, Renewable Energy Supply = 1 kWh

> Hour 2: Grid Energy = 0.0 kWh, Battery Level = 0.0 kWh, Power Consumption = 0.5 kWh, Renewable Energy Supply = 0.5 kWh

> Hour 3: Grid Energy = 0.0 kWh, Battery Level = 0.0 kWh, Power Consumption = 0.5 kWh, Renewable Energy Supply = 0.5 kWh

> Hour 4: Grid Energy = 0.0 kWh, Battery Level = 0.0 kWh, Power Consumption = 1 kWh, Renewable Energy Supply = 1 kWh

> Hour 5: Grid Energy = 0.0 kWh, Battery Level = 0.0 kWh, Power Consumption = 1.5 kWh, Renewable Energy Supply = 2 kWh

> Hour 6: Grid Energy = 0.0 kWh, Battery Level = 0.0 kWh, Power Consumption = 2 kWh, Renewable Energy Supply = 3 kWh

> Hour 7: Grid Energy = 0.0 kWh, Battery Level = 0.0 kWh, Power Consumption = 2.5 kWh, Renewable Energy Supply = 4 kWh

> Hour 8: Grid Energy = 0.0 kWh, Battery Level = 0.0 kWh, Power Consumption = 3 kWh, Renewable Energy Supply = 5 kWh

> Hour 9: Grid Energy = 0.0 kWh, Battery Level = 0.0 kWh, Power Consumption = 3.5 kWh, Renewable Energy Supply = 5 kWh

> Hour 10: Grid Energy = 0.0 kWh, Battery Level = 0.0 kWh, Power Consumption = 3.5 kWh, Renewable Energy Supply = 5 kWh

> Hour 11: Grid Energy = 0.0 kWh, Battery Level = 0.0 kWh, Power Consumption = 3.5 kWh, Renewable Energy Supply = 4 kWh

> Hour 12: Grid Energy = 0.0 kWh, Battery Level = 0.0 kWh, Power Consumption = 3 kWh, Renewable Energy Supply = 4 kWh

> Hour 13: Grid Energy = 0.0 kWh, Battery Level = 0.0 kWh, Power Consumption = 3 kWh, Renewable Energy Supply = 3 kWh

> Hour 14: Grid Energy = 0.0 kWh, Battery Level = 0.0 kWh, Power Consumption = 2.5 kWh, Renewable Energy Supply = 2 kWh

> Hour 15: Grid Energy = 0.0 kWh, Battery Level = 0.0 kWh, Power Consumption = 2.5 kWh, Renewable Energy Supply = 3 kWh
> Hour 16: Grid Energy = 0.0 kWh, Battery Level = 0.0 kWh, Power Consumption = 2.5 kWh, Renewable Energy Supply = 4 kWh

> Hour 17: Grid Energy = 0.0 kWh, Battery Level = 2.0 kWh, Power Consumption = 3 kWh, Renewable Energy Supply = 5 kWh

> Hour 18: Grid Energy = 0.0 kWh, Battery Level = 0.0 kWh, Power Consumption = 3.5 kWh, Renewable Energy Supply = 5 kWh

> Hour 19: Grid Energy = 0.0 kWh, Battery Level = 0.0 kWh, Power Consumption = 3.5 kWh, Renewable Energy Supply = 4 kWh

> Hour 20: Grid Energy = 0.0 kWh, Battery Level = 0.0 kWh, Power Consumption = 3 kWh, Renewable Energy Supply = 3 kWh

> Hour 21: Grid Energy = 0.0 kWh, Battery Level = 0.0 kWh, Power Consumption = 2 kWh, Renewable Energy Supply = 2 kWh

> Hour 22: Grid Energy = 0.0 kWh, Battery Level = 0.0 kWh, Power Consumption = 1.5 kWh, Renewable Energy Supply = 1 kWh

> Hour 23: Grid Energy = 0.0 kWh, Battery Level = 0.0 kWh, Power Consumption = 1 kWh, Renewable Energy Supply = 1 kWh

I tried to change constraints without success.

Answer (score 0):

There are irreconcilable constraints:

- `G[t] + S[t] == D[t]` and `G[t] + S[t] + B[t] == D[t]` don't take into account that the renewable energy supply can be greater than the energy demand; correct: `>=` instead of `==`.
- `B[t] == B[t-1] + Surplus` doesn't take into account the battery's maximum capacity; correct: `<=` instead of `==`.
- `Surplus = max(0, S[t] - D[t])` doesn't take into account a negative surplus, i. e. a deficit, which is to be discharged from the battery; correct: just drop the `max(0,` `)`.

Answer (score 0):

> Grid energy should be used when battery and renewable energy aren't enough but it is 0 at all hours

That's pretty obvious on trivial inspection of your renewable supply versus load. The supply almost always exceeds the load.

More crucially, you're missing explicit variables to capture power flow between all of the valid locations: grid, renewables, battery, load.

```py
import pandas as pd
import pulp

index = pd.RangeIndex(name='hour', start=0, stop=24)
B_max = 10     # Maximum battery capacity
B_init = 0     # Initial battery level

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        # Grid energy draw cost per unit for each hour
        'grid_unit_cost': (
            0.15, 0.15, 0.14, 0.13, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.14, 0.16, 0.18, 0.20,
            0.20, 0.20, 0.18, 0.16, 0.14, 0.18, 0.20, 0.20, 0.20, 0.18, 0.16, 0.15,
        ),
        # Renewable energy supply for each hour
        'renew_supply': (
            1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4,
            4, 3,   2,   3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1,
        ),
        # Energy demand for each hour
        'load': (
            0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5,
            3.0, 3.0, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0, 1.5, 1.0,
        ),

        # Power flows through the hour
        'grid_to_batt': pulp.LpVariable.matrix(
            name='grid_to_batt', indices=index, cat=pulp.LpContinuous, lowBound=0,
        ),
        'grid_to_load': pulp.LpVariable.matrix(
            name='grid_to_load', indices=index, cat=pulp.LpContinuous, lowBound=0,
        ),
        'renew_to_batt': pulp.LpVariable.matrix(
            name='renew_to_batt', indices=index, cat=pulp.LpContinuous, lowBound=0,
        ),
        'batt_to_load': pulp.LpVariable.matrix(
            name='batt_to_load', indices=index, cat=pulp.LpContinuous, lowBound=0,
        ),

        # Battery charge at the end of the hour
        'batt_charge': pulp.LpVariable.matrix(
            name='batt_charge', indices=index, cat=pulp.LpContinuous, lowBound=0, upBound=B_max,
        ),
    },
    index=index,
)
df['renew_to_load'] = df['load'] - df['grid_to_load'] - df['batt_to_load']
df['grid_draw'] = df['grid_to_batt'] + df['grid_to_load']
df['grid_cost'] = df['grid_draw'] * df['grid_unit_cost']

prob = pulp.LpProblem(name="Energy_Cost_Minimization", sense=pulp.LpMinimize)
prob.setObjective(pulp.lpSum(df['grid_cost']))

prev_charge = B_init

for hour, row in df.iterrows():
    next_charge = prev_charge + row['grid_to_batt'] + row['renew_to_batt'] - row['batt_to_load']
    prob.addConstraint(row['renew_to_batt'] + row['renew_to_load'] <= row['renew_supply'])
    prob.addConstraint(row['batt_charge'] == next_charge)
    prev_charge = next_charge

print(prob)
prob.solve()
assert prob.status == pulp.LpStatusOptimal

affine_cols = ['renew_to_load', 'grid_draw', 'grid_cost']
df[affine_cols] = df[affine_cols].map(pulp.LpAffineExpression.value)
var_cols = ['grid_to_batt', 'grid_to_load', 'renew_to_batt', 'batt_to_load', 'batt_charge']
df[var_cols] = df[var_cols].map(pulp.LpVariable.value)

pd.options.display.max_columns = 24
pd.options.display.width = 200
print(df.T)
```

```
hour              0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10   11   12   13    14    15    16    17   18   19   20    21    22    23
grid_unit_cost  0.15  0.15  0.14  0.13  0.12  0.12  0.12  0.12  0.14  0.16  0.18  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.18  0.16  0.14  0.18  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.18  0.16  0.15
renew_supply    1.00  1.00  0.50  0.50  1.00  2.00  3.00  4.00  5.00  5.00  5.00  4.0  4.0  3.0  2.00  3.00  4.00  5.00  5.0  4.0  3.0  2.00  1.00  1.00
load            0.50  0.50  0.50  0.50  1.00  1.50  2.00  2.50  3.00  3.50  3.50  3.5  3.0  3.0  2.50  2.50  2.50  3.00  3.5  3.5  3.0  2.00  1.50  1.00
grid_to_batt    0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.00  0.00  0.00
grid_to_load    0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.00  0.00  0.00
renew_to_batt   0.50  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.00  0.00  0.00
batt_to_load    0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.50  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.00  0.50  0.00
batt_charge     0.50  0.50  0.50  0.50  0.50  0.50  0.50  0.50  0.50  0.50  0.50  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.50  0.00  0.00
renew_to_load   0.50  0.50  0.50  0.50  1.00  1.50  2.00  2.50  3.00  3.50  3.50  3.5  3.0  3.0  2.00  2.50  2.50  3.00  3.5  3.5  3.0  2.00  1.00  1.00
grid_draw       0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.00  0.00  0.00
grid_cost       0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.00  0.00  0.00
```